# How to assign values to a void array

Tags: c, arrays, void-pointers

After discovering, that there are no templates in C, I decided to use pointer array in my quest to create dynamic array on my own.

I decided that this answer might be a good start, however, it only considers integer array, which does not suit my needs completely. For that I decided to change it to a void array.

My structure currently looks like this:

```
typedef struct {
  void *array;
  size_t length;  //How many spaces in array are occupied at the moment
  size_t size;    //How many spaces were allocated
  size_t elm_size;//How large one member of the array is
} Array;
```

My concern is, how to set the elements of such array. I plan to get them using my function `array_get`. The matter is, that `variable[n]` operator makes no sense for the `void` array, since this operator means `*(variable + sizeof(variable)*n)` and for `void`, size is zero. At this point you'd agree that following would be a legitimate way to retrieve an element:

```
void* array_get(Array *a, size_t offset) {
  if(offset>=a->used) {
    println("Error: access of undefined offset in array.");
    exit(1);
  }
  return void* (((char*)array) + offset*a->elm_size);
}
```

In program then:

```
int retrieved_value;
retrieved_value = *((int*)array_get(&my_array, 2)); //The outer star is for dereferencing
```

However, on setting the elements, I'm helpless.

<sup>Please do not think I plan on setting the values at random. I'm aware that a memory must be allocated first.</sup>

As I side question for those who like to give those perfect answers that sometimes appear here on SO, I'd like to ask how would I make a function to push a member to an array. Again, `void` would cause a lot of trouble here, see:

```
void array_push(Array *a, void* element) {
  if (a->used == a->size) {
    a->size *= 2;
    a->array = (int *)realloc(a->array, a->size * sizeof(int));
  }
  /*array set expression*/ = *(element); //Error! Can't dereference void pointer. Size unknown!
}
```

But there must be a `void*` argument for the size of array member is to be decided in the runtime. So I wonder how to cast `void*` to `var_of_sizex*`. At that point, I'd apply `Array.elm_size`, but I'm not aware of such flexible variable type.

Comment: You can use `memcpy` to copy the bytes from the input into the appropriate place in the array, using the same offset calculation as in `array_get`.

Comment: Shouldn't `a->used` be `a->size`?

Comment: In fact, `a->used` is `a->length`, but thakns for pointing the confusion out, I'll correct that. And yes, `mempcpy` is exactly the thing I failed to think about - and will solve my problem I suppose.

Comment: +1 for starting your question with ... After discovering that C doesn't have templates ... :-)

Comment: `array_push` should reallocate the array if necessary and then call `array_set`.

Comment: I must disagree with your `array_set` logic @Barmar. In cases you'd need to set specific offset, like location on chess map (or any other), you'd know the array size and therefore would not be using dynamic array. In case of offsets that might differ, a mapped (associative) array is, I think, the right solution.

Comment: I'm not sure what you're saying. My `array_set` logic is simply based on your `array_get` logic. However, I just noticed an error in both, `(char*)array` should be `(char*)(a->array)`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
void array_set(Array *a, size_t offset, void* new_value) {
    if (offset >= a->size) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Error: assigning beyond end of array.\n");
        exit(1);
    }
    memcpy(((char*)(a->array)) + offset*a->elm_size, new_value, a->elm_size);
}
```

Depending on how you want to do things, you might want to move the `realloc` logic from `array_push` to `array_set`. So `array_set` would automatically grow the array rather than report an error when you try to write beyond the end.

Comment: You may want to make sure he sticks with C and uses printf :P

Comment: Oh, one more thing I came across - how do I turn a constant into a void pointer, to push constant values (this might only be needed during debug, but still)?

Comment: I don't think you can. Constants don't necessarily have an address, because the compiler might turn them into immediate data or store them in registers.